# Get-Help * throws exception Get-Help: unable to find type [uint8]

Tags: powershell

Windows 10 pro x64, 21H2 19044.1526 , Powershell 5.1

```
Get-Help *
```

throws exception

> "Get-Help: Unable to find type [uint8]"

This command throws the exception even when run
at the interactive powershell command line, after displaying some output.

I'm running powershell with admin privilege. I ran Update-Help but the syptom did not change, although Update-Help
took a long time, added lots of content, but reported ResourceUnavailable exception for ConfigDefender, ConfigDefenderPerformance, PSReadline for UI culture {en-US}.

EDIT 1:

After a reboot, in an elevated Powershell session:
`[uint8] | Get-Member`
throws the same exception while `[byte] | Get-Member` works correctly.

As per suggestions below, in an elevated cmd:

`dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`
completed successfully, followed by:

`sfc /scannow` found corrupt files and repaired them, but the symptom remains unchanged `[uint8] | Get-Member` reports exception Unable to find type, also after a reboot.

EDIT 2:
As the same symptom happens on different machines (all Windows-10 x64 pro), I suspect that something needs to be loaded in the powershell session first , even if that was not the intention of Get-Help. Some namespace, module, assembly etc. I also found some specific `Get-Help` commands for specific topics that throw the same exception, as shown below:

```
Get-Help -Full  Get-DOPercentageMaxBackgroundBandwidth  | Out-String
Get-Help -Full  Start-AutologgerConfig  | Out-String 
Get-Help -Full  Flush-EtwTraceSession  | Out-String 
Get-Help -Full  New-ProvisioningRepro  | Out-String 
Get-Help -Full  Resume-ProvisioningSession  | Out-String
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like you've got a cmdlet with an invalid type signature - you can reproduce the issue with ```PS> function aaa([uint8] $aaa) { }; get-help aaa```. To find the invalid cmdlet you could use something like ```$cmds = Get-Command -ListImported; $cmds | foreach-object { write-host $_.Name; $null = Get-Help $_.Name }``` - if you get the same error then the last cmdlet displayed on screen is the broken one. If that doesn't work, try ```Get-Command``` without the ```-ListImported```, but that will be a lot slower as it'll import all the modules it finds on disk.

Comment: As I'm reading this, and sitting her thinking about your problem, it seems to me that your problem could be missing or corrupt files, and from Microsoft's site it says: "Use the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files".  Just a wild shot in the dark, but I've done it enough to know that it sometimes fixes files, and at the very least tells if there is a problem.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e

Comment: @mclayton No errors reported from the -ListImported suggestion, but as per edit to question `[uint8] | Get-Member` throws same exception. So some component related to WMI is missing.

Answer (score 0):

uint8 is a wmi type and is recognised as byte in PowerShell. It's a bit odd that it's coming up at all.

As a first step, I would attempt to figure out if the type uint8 is loaded into powershell at all:

```
[unit8] | Get-Member
```

If you see an error that says unable to find type, that suggests that at some point some component of WMI may have gotten tangled up in your PS Help.

To be sure that the powershell equivalent is definitely working do:

```
[byte] | Get-Member
```

You should hopefully see some sort of output.

If both of the above checks workout as described you could feasibly stop the search there - everything's working, there's just the niggle of a uint8 type popping up when you try to get-help *

You might have some luck in this area by running a Garbage Collection, wait 10 - 20 minutes then restart your powershell session and check if the problem persists:

```
[GC]::Collect()
```

Perhaps follow this up by updating the modules for the affected cmdlets to hopefully resolve any potential issues adding the type when the modules are being loaded into your environment:

```
@mao - Sorry got a bit more info here: https://powershell.one/wmi/datatypes#uint8
```

Based on this info, it looks as though those cmdlets specifically may not be correctly initialising the uint8 type in your environment if they do indeed use it.

Give this a shot to update them:

```
Get-Command "Get-DOPercentageMaxBackgroundBandwidth",
    "Start-AutologgerConfig",
    "Flush-EtwTraceSession",
    "New-ProvisioningRepro",
    "Resume-ProvisioningSession" |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Module |
Sort-Object -Unique Name |
Foreach-Object {Update-Module -Name $_.Name}
```

Comment: As per edit to question, it appears there is some missing component, as `[uint8] | Get-Member` throws the same exception.

Comment: @mao - might seem like a silly question - have you tried updating nuget / package manager etc? Failing that, what about group policy components is that being used in your environment? The cmdlets you mention mostly have a tie into some sort of deployment/configuration management

Comment: @mao - Sorry got a bit more info here: https://powershell.one/wmi/datatypes#uint8

Based on this info, it looks as though those cmdlets specifically may not be correctly initialising the uint8 type in your environment if they do indeed use it.

Give this a shot to update them:

Get-Command "Get-DOPercentageMaxBackgroundBandwidth",
 "Start-AutologgerConfig",
 "Flush-EtwTraceSession",
 "New-ProvisioningRepro",
 "Resume-ProvisioningSession" |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Module |
Sort-Object -Unique Name |
Foreach-Object {Update-Module -Name $_.Name} <<<< I've added this above :)